# The Solution to the system of linear PDEs

Tags: differential-equations

I am looking for the solution to the following system:
$$ f_t(t,x) = -tx g(t,x), g_t(t,x) = (1-t)x f(t,x). $$

The equation comes from the integral equation
$$ f(t,x)=1+ x \int_{0}^{1-t} (1-s)f(s,x)ds, $$
which is obtained from certain combinatorial generating function.
 Would you please give some comments on this?

Comment: Unless there is a typo, this is an ODE with x as additional parameter.

Comment: Yes, we can think it as a system of ODEs...

Comment: First : the $x$ parameter is irrelevant, it just multiplies the vector field so that it just gives a scaling in time. Second : what do you want to know ?

Comment: Can we find the closed form or the explicit expression of the solution $f(t, x), g(t, x),$  not a series solution?